# Multiple fragments in each page of a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I want my app to show an multiple charts in a `ViewPager` (One chart per page) and have a button in each chart when I touch it the app shows a table with the raw data.

Here is an example of a possible scenario:

The app shows chart1 when I slide, it shows chart2. But when I touch the button it shows the raw data of the first chart.
And when the app shows raw data and I slide  it show the raw data of the next chart. At each time I can go back to showing charts.

**EDIT**
Here is something I tried (I'm only using `TextView`s so far untill I have something working)

And it's not working nor throwing an exception.

```
public class PageGaucheFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_one_layout,container, false);
    v.findViewById(R.id.tv1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.layout_one, RawFragment.newInstance());
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

`RawFragment` inflates this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

viewpager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentsSliderActivity.java

```
public class FragmentsSliderActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageGaucheFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageMilieuFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageDroiteFragment.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

    PageIndicator mIndicator = (PageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
}
}
```

MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragments
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: did you coded anything ?

Comment: I added some code, but it's not working. I'm not sure if what I've done can lead to something that's why I didn't show it at first.